# Сколько памяти выделено под переменную?

Tags: c++, память

А с помощью какой функции можно узнать, сколько памяти выделено под переменную в языке С++?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44994/discussion-on-question-by-muller-----). Пожалуйста, перенесите все существенные подробности в вопрос или в ответ(ы).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет такой функции.

У типа есть размер, который можно узнать при помощи `sizeof`.
Однако размер реально выделенной памяти может отличаться:

- при выделении "в куче" (при помощи `new`) скорее всего будет выделено больше, т.к. куча может выравнивать свои блоки, например на 16 байт.
- при выделении "на стеке" размер может быть как больше, из за выравнивания фреймов стека, так и меньше - компилятор может поместить две несвязанные переменные в одно место памяти.
- при статическом выделении переменной (`static`), может происходить всё то же самое, плюс могут создаваться дополнительные объекты для обеспечения потокобезопасности.

Comment: Можно сказать, что сумма sizeof-ов не  равна выделенной памяти.

Comment: В куче дополнительно ещё выделяется несколько байтов под хранение размера выделенной области (в большинстве реализаций) + дополнительная служебная информация для менеджера кучи.

Comment: Хуже того, если в классе есть указатель на другой объект, не понятно, является ли этот другой объект _частью_ исходного объекта или нет, и нужно ли считать его память тоже.